# C++ sending a packet over socket

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm trying to communicate with a server program I installed. The server sends and receives all data in the form of constructed packets that follow the setup of:
int int int string nullbyte
like this:

little endian signed int -> The size of the ID (4 bytes) + size of Type (4 bytes) + size of Body (minimum 1 for null terminator) + null byte for a minimum of 10 as the value;

little endian signed int -> id

little endian signed int -> packet type

Null terminiated ascii string -> body

null byte

I've managed to read the packets just fine but when I try to send the packet with the password, the server completely ignores it which means the packet is wrong some how. I construct the packet like this:

```
void Packet::build(){

/*
 * Create unsigned char vector to store
 * the data while we build the byte array
 * and create a pointer so the byte array can
 * be modified by the required functions.
 */
std::vector<unsigned char> packet(m_size);
unsigned char *ptr = packet.data();

/*
 * Convert each of the three integers as well
 * as the string into bytes which will be stored
 * back into the memory that ptr points to.
 *
 * Packet data follows format:
 * int32 -> Size of ID + Server Data + body (minimum of 10).
 * int32 -> ID of request. Used to match to response.
 * int32 -> Server Data type. Identifies type of request.
 * String -> Minimum of 1 byte for null terminator.
 * String -> Null terminator.
 */
storeInt32Le(ptr, m_sizeInPacket);
storeInt32Le(ptr, m_requestID);
storeInt32Le(ptr, m_serverData);
storeStringNt(ptr, m_body);

/*
 * Store the vector in member variable m_cmdBytes;
 *
 */
m_cmdBytes = packet;
}
```

storeInt32Le:

```
void Packet::storeInt32Le(unsigned char* &buffer, int32_t value) {
/*
 * Copy the integer to a byte array using
 * bitwise AND with mask to ensure the right
 * bits are copied to each segment then
 * increment the pointer by 4 for the next
 * iteration.
 */
buffer[0] = value & 0xFF;
buffer[1] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
buffer[2] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
buffer[3] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
buffer += 4;
}
```

storeStringNt:

```
void Packet::storeStringNt(unsigned char* &buffer, const string &s) {
/*
 * Get the size of the string to be copied
 * then do a memcpy of string char array to
 * the buffer.
 */
size_t size = s.size() + 1;
memcpy(buffer, s.c_str(), size);
buffer += size;
```

}

And finally, I send it with:

```
bool Connection::sendCmd(Packet packet) {
unsigned char *pBytes = packet.bytes().data();
size_t size = packet.size();

while (size > 0){
    int val = send(m_socket, pBytes, size, 0);

    if (val <= 0) {
        return false;
    }

    pBytes += val;
    size -= val;
}

return true;
}
```

Packet::bytes() just returns m_cmdBytes

Comment: You need to check whether `val` is > 0 but < `packet.size()`; it may not send all the data in one go. You might want to use a debugger (or logging) to see if your packet looks right before sending it, so you can see if it is the construction or transmission that is the problem. (Or even use wireshark to see exactly what is being sent.)

Comment: Your memcpy-call is wrong: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/ By the way, why don't you copy the bytes directly to `packet`?

Comment: I added a small little check for val == packet.size() where it outputs to console saying the entire packet was sent and it is responding.

Comment: @tkausl You're right, I am using memcpy wrong. c.c Sorry about that, I am coming to C++ from C# so I'm still learning all of these functions, lol. Thank you for the link, that will help me a lot. I changed the memcpy functions.

Comment: Your code bakes your machine's representation of integers into your wire protocol. That's generally not a sensible thing to do.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm not sure what you mean. Like I said, coming from C# so I'm probably in over my head with this program but I'm working hard to learn it. In C# all I had to do was easy. Packet[0] = Command.length() + 9; for each int and Packet[12 + X] = System::Text::Encoding::Default->GetBytes(Command[X])[0]; put that in a loop

Comment: @AlexisShepard David's point is you state that integers are defined in the protocol as little endian, but you make no attempt to ensure that the integers are sent as little endian.

Comment: @AlexisShepard: also, most network protocols use *big endian* (aka "network byte order") when sending multi-byte integers, so it is a little unusual that this protocol is using *little endian* instead.

Comment: What if the next version of your platform uses more than four bytes to store integers? What if it stores integers in some form other than little endian? You are baking into your code assumptions about your platform. Unless you have a really good reason for doing that, don't do it. It's easy to not do that.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Ok, I get what you mean, but I've been searching google for three days on how to send integers but everything I could find showed what I'm doing or similar.  So how can I ensure that I'm using little endian 32 bit integers?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think they use it because it's designed to run on x86 linux/windows systems which lean towards little endian (I think).

Comment: @AlexisShepard At a minimum, just make a function that copies the integer into a provided buffer and document clearly what it does. At least that way you can port the code by only changing one function. Also, look at types like `uint32_t` and libraries like [boost endian](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/endian/doc/conversion.html).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments, you are:

- making *assumptions* about the byte size and endian of your compiler's `int` data type.  Since your protocol requires a very specific byte size and endian for its integers, you need to force your code to follow those requirements when preparing the packet.
- using `memcpy()` incorrectly.  You have the source and destination buffers reversed.
- are not ensuring that `send()` is actually sending the full packet correctly.

Try something more like this:

```
void store_uint32_le(unsigned char* &buffer, uint32_t value)
{
    buffer[0] = value & 0xFF;
    buffer[1] = (value >> 8)  & 0xFF;
    buffer[2] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
    buffer[3] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
    buffer += 4;
}

void store_string_nt(unsigned char* &buffer, const std::string &s)
{
    size_t size = s.size() + 1;
    memcpy(buffer, s.c_str(), size);
    buffer += size;
}

...

std::vector<unsigned char> packet(13 + m_body.size());

unsigned char *ptr = packet.data(); // or = &packet[0] prior to C++11
store_uint32_le(ptr, packet.size() - 4);
store_uint32_le(ptr, m_requestID);
store_uint32_le(ptr, m_serverData);
store_string_nt(ptr, m_body);

...

unsigned char *pBytes = packet.data(); // or = &packet[0] prior to C++11
size_t size = packet.size();
while (size > 0)
{
    int val = send(m_socket, pBytes, size, 0);
    if (val < 0)
    {
        // if your socket is non-blocking, enable this...
        /*
        #ifdef _WINDOWS // check your compiler for specific defines...
        if (WSAGetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
        #else
        if ((errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK) || (errno == EINTR))
        #endif
            continue;
        */

        return false;
    }

    if (val == 0)
        return false;

    pBytes += val;
    size -= val;
}

return true;
```

Comment: Obviously, I don't want to just use this code without understanding it so I have a couple questions. First, you're using uint32_t but I need signed integers, would I want to use int32_t instead? Secondly, why does buffer have += 4 in store_uint32_le? EDIT: Wait, I remember this part, it moves the pointer to the next spot! Sorry, I'm really new to C++ and feel like an idiot right now.

Comment: You *can* use `int32_t`, but `uint32_t` is better, especially for values that are never negative, like byte sizes. If you don't exceed the max value of `int32_t`, the receiver won't know the difference. As for the functions, `buffer` is passed by reference so the functions can advance the pointer forward after writing bytes to the memory being pointed to. This way the caller doesn't have to advance the pointer between function calls, eg: `store_uint32_le(ptr, m_size - 4); ptr += 4; store_uint32_le(ptr, m_requestID); ptr += 4; store_uint32_le(ptr, m_serverData); ptr += 4; ...`

Comment: The one value m_requestID can be returned negative. If you send the SERVERDATA_AUTH type with the wrong password, it returns with -1.

Comment: Still working with this. I think I've implemented the code correctly. I'll edit my original post so you can see the new code. For some reason the server still isn't responding to me but it sends these "keep alive" packets and I've been reading those perfectly so I know it isn't a reading issue.